# How to replace a standard httpd package with httpd24-httpd from Software Collections?

Tags: apache, centos7, software-collections

I am setting up a CentOS 7 server as the migration target of my old CentOS 6 server.

With the state of system updates being so slow, I was thinking of using a more reactive or up-to-date repository for Apache httpd. This is out of security concerns (https://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_24.html).

I came across SCL months ago but despite hours and hours of documentation reading and web browsing, I haven't yet found a way to have httpd24-http from SCL replace the standard httpd package, in the same way that mariadb packages are a drop-in replacement for mysql packages.

**Is it possible to do without httpd from the default repository and instead have httpd24-httpd from SCL and how?**

The thing that has me asking this question is that some packages (e.g. phpMyAdmin and roundcubemail) seem to not see the package from SCL and pull in httpd, which gets installed as a dependency.

I am still somehow confused as to whether Apache httpd (2.4.39 atm) from the SCL is a replacement or whether it's supposed to be installed alongside httpd (2.4.6 atm), in which case, I am wondering whether there is much use since both programs will try to bind to port 80 and port 443. I'm surely missing a few key points in understanding the SCL ecosystem, specifically concerning httpd or similar daemons.

EDIT
I finally understood that the SCL version is to be installed alongside the standard httpd. Also, the standard http receives security backports, which answers my initial need.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to swap httpd from scl with the standard httpd
I've done the same with php versions.
scl enable httpd24 bash
https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/httpd24/

I'm asking myself the same question because I'd like to enable TLS 1.3 for centos 7, but besides the httpd, it will also need a manually installed version of openssl to make that possible at the moment.

Comment: The need to use `scl enable` commands is a powerful deterrent. I'm building the new server with Ansible and I don't see how that would fit in. How would a `yum install phpMyAdmin` fit with that, I don't see either. For now, I've reverted to the default httpd. I've found the Remi repo for PHP and I've just found out that MariaDB has repositories for CentOS 7. Once I've modified my scripts to account for those new repos, I will no longer need to scratch my head due to SCL. A second deterrent is that SCL versions are also lagging behind.